# origyear for geschichtsfrkl (biblatex package)

Tags: biblatex

For almost all biblatex styles the following macro adds an original year to the publishing year. But not so in the **geschichtsfrkl** style package which I am using. I don't want to change the style for several reasons. But it would be a feature which I regularly need to add the original year.

Working Example: [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/njbwvnkghjvb)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,BCOR=48mm,12pt,titlepage]{jurabook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw, nopublisher=false, journalnumber=afteryear, addyear=true, origfields=false]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \printdate
  \iffieldundef{origyear}{%
  }{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext[parens]{\printorigdate}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{schaeffer1977traite,
  author    = {Schaeffer, Pierre},
  title     = {Traité des objets musicaux: essai interdisciplines},
  year      = {1977},
  origdate  = {1966},
  location  = {Paris},
  publisher = {Editions du Seuil},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How can I archive an original year output with the geschichtsfrkl package? (The example below shows the missing original year in parens.)

geschichtsfrkl example (not working) [Overleaf2](https://www.overleaf.com/read/kzwtnsnjtcjd)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,BCOR=48mm,12pt,titlepage]{jurabook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=geschichtsfrkl]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \printdate
  \iffieldundef{origyear}{%
  }{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext[parens]{\printorigdate}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{schaeffer1977traite,
  author    = {Schaeffer, Pierre},
  title     = {Traité des objets musicaux: essai interdisciplines},
  year      = {1977},
  origdate  = {1966},
  location  = {Paris},
  publisher = {Editions du Seuil},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know better?

Answer (score 3):

For the `geschichtsfrkl` style you need to modify the `location+edition+year` macro. You can see this by looking through `geschichtsfrkl.bbx`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,BCOR=48mm,12pt,titlepage]{jurabook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=geschichtsfrkl]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{location+edition+year}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iffieldundef{edition}{\setunit{\addspace}}{%
       \iffieldint{edition}%
           {\setunit{\addspace}%
             \mkbibsuperscript{\printfield{edition}}}%
           {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
             \printfield{edition}\addcomma\addspace}}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{\printorigdate}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{schaeffer1977traite,
  author    = {Schaeffer, Pierre},
  title     = {Traité des objets musicaux: essai interdisciplines},
  year      = {1977},
  origdate  = {1966},
  location  = {Paris},
  publisher = {Editions du Seuil},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]